# Random loops after generating an amount of numbers

Tags: .net, vb.net, random

Im trying to play song in a random order, after it has played all songs, all become `nextMusic.WasPlayed = False` and the random number generator keeps generating numbers, but after it has played some of the songs again the generator enters a loop and keeps generating numbers without stop

```
     Dim RanTrack As Random = New Random(TimeOfDay.Millisecond)
     Private Sub nextBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nextBTN.Click
        If My.Settings.Shufle = True Then
  generateNumber:
            Dim trackN As Integer = RanTrack.Next(musicControl.Controls.Count - 1)
                Debug.WriteLine("number " & trackN)
                Dim nextMusic As MusicItem = musicControl.Controls.Item(trackN)
                If nextMusic.WasPlayed = False Then
                    nextMusic.PlayMusic()
                Else
                    GoTo generateNumber
                End If
         End If
      End Sub
```

Comment: Are you really using a "GoTo"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
Dim RanTrack As Random = New Random()
Private Sub nextBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nextBTN.Click
    If My.Settings.Shufle = True Then
        Dim nextMusics = ( _
            From nextMusic In musicControl.Controls.Cast(Of MusicItem)() _
            Where nextMusic.WasPlayed = False _
            Order By RanTrack.NextDouble() _
            Select nextMusic).ToArray()
        If nextMusics.Any() Then
            nextMusics(0).PlayMusic()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```